# How to Provide a View in Dagger2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Below is the Activity, it is still using an old DI model, and i'm trying to migrate to Dagger2 (with dagger-android). I want to inject the Presenter, and as you can see, one dependency is the 'NewProjectDisplayer' which is a custom view in the activity.

[image]

This is the 'NewProjectDisplayer' which I want to provide to the Presenter

[image]

I have a Module (AppModule) which provides the global dependencies like ProjectService, LoginService etc..

Below is the NewProjectModule which I am having trouble with. One of the dependencies which is tied to the activity is the 'NewProjectDisplayer'. And I have no idea how I can provide it..

```
@Module
public class NewProjectActivityModule {

    @Provides
    NewProjectDisplayer provideNewProjectDisplayer(View view) {
        // ??? return view.findViewById(R.id.create_project_view);
    }

    @Provides
    NewProjectNavigator provideNewProjectNavigator(BaseActivity baseActivity) {
        return new AndroidNewProjectNavigator(baseActivity);
    }

    @Provides
    NewProjectPresenter provideNewProjectPresenter(NewProjectDisplayer displayer, //
                                                   ProjectService projectService,
                                                   LoginService loginService,
                                                   UserService userService,
                                                   NewProjectNavigator navigator, //
                                                   PermissionHandler permissionHandler,//
                                                   CropImageHandler cropImageHandler,//
                                                   RxSchedulers schedulers) {
        return new NewProjectPresenter(displayer, projectService, loginService,
                userService, navigator, permissionHandler, cropImageHandler, schedulers);
    }

}
```

How can I provide this 'NewProjectDisplayer' so that the Presenter can be created and injected? I am using dagger-android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't provide or do a `findViewById` on an activity module that is compatible with `dagger-android`, one reason being that the module is created before the view is actually on the hierarchy. Also, doing this is a not a good practice, but if you're still convinced you should do this, you could try creating a sub component that will have a module that provides the view dependency and it has to be created after `setContentView`, as suggested by @elmorabea.

Comment: Yeah that sucks, I guess I could make the activity implement the same displayer interface and delegate to the compoundview, but that would create really ugly code. I think the easiest thing would just be to replace all views with Fragments

Comment: You could also pass the instance of the view outside the constructor. Many people do this with `attach()` and `detach()` methods.

Comment: Yeah using `attach(NewProjectDisplayer displayer)..` worked out for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just solving your problem, not sure if you should provide views with Dagger though.

Change your module to be something like that.

```
@Module
public class NewProjectActivityModule {

private View view;

public NewProjectActivityModule (View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

@Provides
NewProjectDisplayer provideNewProjectDisplayer(View view) {
    return view;
}

}
```

However, where ever you are creating your Dagger component you need to do something like that.

```
YourDaggerComponent.builder().newProjectActivityModule(new NewProjectActivityModule (yourViewInstance)).build();
```

Otherwise it will crash at run-time.

Comment: This is for the old dagger right? I'm trying to use the new dagger-android and there you dont build the component, instead just use the AndroidInjection.inject(this)